# RS485 transmission errors

Tags: transmission-line, rs485

I am trying to get two Atmega328ps to talk to each other over RS485 with MAX485 as transceiver. Below is the scope trace of D+ and D-. [image]

Yellow : 485A line, 
Cyan : 485B line, 
Blue: A - B (Differential)

Here it is a simple transition from 1 to 0, however the waveforms appear corrupted.

Currently the configuration is 9600 8-N-1. There are only 2 nodes and 120 ohm terminating resistors are installed on both ends. 
I also added fail safe bias resistors (560 ohm) on one side as per standard suggestions but it did not help. 
Currently one node transmits 8 bytes every 500ms and the other reads them and displays them on 7 segment display. Due to this corruption, incorrect values are displayed.

I have tried to simply send data to a PC (through RS485-USB converter) and view that data though PuTTY, RealTerm etc and see nonsense data. I have tried multiple baud rates, odd/even parity without success. Sending data from PC and echoing it back results in garbage data.

Any ideas to solve this issue are greatly appreciated.

Edit: Schematic as requested. 
[image: Max485]
[image: Atmega328p]

Comment: Also both Atmega328p use 14.7456 Mhz crystal. I have confirmed that baud rate settings for both are accurate.

Comment: Post a schematics of both parts. Seems strange that A(yellow) and B(cyan) line have the same polarity. They should be negated.

Comment: I bet you use TX_ENABLE. It looks like between 0 and 1 you go high Z. Which is fine for end of transmission, but should not be done during transmission.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum Hmm, looks like it might be related to that. However I started having this issue 3 days ago, I suspected it to be software related. Thats when I changed code to switch TX_ENABLE but the problem has persisted.  So this problem stays regardless of anything related to TX_ENABLE. During this testing, I have also tried without switching TX_ENABLE, by keeping one node permanently sending and the other permanently receiving but I still get transmission errors.

Comment: Don't trust the code. Check TX_ENABLE with your scope. Takes a few seconds, and then you can be sure. Can you post a photo of the layout?

Comment: @peufeu Yup, just did that ! TX_ENABLE should remain on throughout the packet but just as Gregory said it dips just at the end of the bit. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: The 120 ohm termination resistor goes parallel to A,B not in series! You may probably need to connect GND to both devices.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič The 120 ohm resistor is parallel to A,B. I have added a user selectable jumper to enable or disable it, depending on if user wants termination or not. Scope images are with both GND connected.

Comment: Probe your 5V rail, make sure your power is not drooping during the communications